# ¿Cómo guardar los datos del componente Padre en el useState del componente hijo en React?

Tags: react-hooks

Del componente **Padre** le paso al componente **hijo** un **array** de objetos atraves de **props**.
Cuando el componente **hijo** recibe la data del **props**, quiero guardardarla en el **useSate**.
De la forma que lo hice no me muestra errores, pero cuando intento hacer el **map** para recorrer los
datos del **useState**, no muestra nada.
Funciona si directamente hago **props.operations.map** para mostrar los datos en la tabla, lo que pasa es que mas adelante voy a necesitar manipular el estado, por eso decidí utilizar **useState**.

**Componente Padre**

```js
const [stateOperations, setStateOperations] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
 getOperations('ingreso');
}, []);

const getOperations = async (type) => {
  const data = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4000/api/operations/filter/clau@gmail.com/${type}`
  );
  const operationsData = await data.json();
  console.log(operationsData);
  setStateOperations(operationsData);
};

return(
  <OperationsList operations={stateOperations} />
);
```

**Componente hijo OperationsList**

```js
const OperationsList = (props) => {
 // cargando la data del props en el useState 
 const[stateOperations, setStateOperations] = React.useState(props.operations)
 let cont = 1;

 return(
  <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Concepto</th>
              <th>Monto</th>
              <th>Tipo</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {stateOperations.map((item) => (
              <tr key={cont++}>
                <td>
                  {moment(item.registration_date)
                    .subtract(10, "days")
                    .calendar()}
                </td>
                <td>{item.concept}</td>
                <td>{item.amount}</td>
                <td>{item.type}</td>
                <td>{item.category}</td>
                <div className="text-center">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
                  </button>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
  </Table>
 
 );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución sería asignar el nuevo estado dentro de `useEffect` (en tu componente hijo) para que al momento de entrar y/o llamar al componente, éste *setee* los valores por defecto al `state`.

```js
 const [stateOperations, setStateOperations] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
    setStateOperations(props.operations)
 }, [props.operations])
```

La causa es que el estado no alcanza a ser actualizado cuando se renderiza la información, sino que ocurre posteriormente.

Nos comentas que tal te va!

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera!, hice unas modificaciones en tu código ya que faltaban 2 detalles: como props envia un array faltaban los corchetes [] en el useState  y ademas en el useEfect faltaba  [props.operations])

Comment: Genial! Se me había pasado eso... un abrazo!